# Postgres: reading the results of 'returning *' into a variable

Tags: sql, postgresql

All the examples I have found for the Postgres 'returning' functionality (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dml-returning.html) return values for a single row.
How do I read multiple result rows into a variable?

Executing the following outside a function gives the desired results:

```
create sequence core.test_id_seq start with 10000;
create table core.test (
    test_id integer not null default nextval('core.test_id_seq'),
    field integer not null
);
insert into core.test ( field )
select unnest( array[1, 2] ) as id
returning *
;
 test_id | field
---------+-------
   10000 |     1
   10001 |     2
(2 rows)
```

But I want to read the results into a variable or table to work with:

```
do $$
declare
    recs ??;
begin
    create sequence core.test_id_seq start with 10000;
    create table core.test (
        test_id integer not null default nextval('core.test_id_seq'),
        field integer not null
    );
    insert into core.test ( field )
    select unnest( array[1, 2] ) as id
    returning * into recs
    ;
end $$;
```

Is this possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  need to use an array of integers:

```
do $$
declare
   new_ids int[];
begin
  with new_rows as (
    insert into core.test ( field )
    select unnest( array[1, 2] ) as id
    returning *
  ) 
  select array_agg(field)
    into new_ids
  from new_rows;
   
  ... work with the new_ids array ...
  
end 
$$;
```

Comment: My actual problem used mixed datatypes, but this got me started in the right direction. The 'with' clause allows you to get at whatever you want. Thx!